# Class member method - return type template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Is it possible to do this in C++11 in some clean way

```
class Foo 
{
   public:
     Foo(Bar1 * b1, Bar2 * b2) : bar1(b1), bar2(b2) {}
     template <typename T> T * GetData<T>();
   private:
      Bar1 * bar1;
      Bar2 * bar2;
};

template <> Bar1 * Foo::GetData<Bar1>() { return this->bar1;}
template <> Bar2 * Foo::GetData<Bar2>() { return this->bar2;}
```

And in main code

```
Foo * foo = new Foo(new Bar1(), new Bar2());
Bar1 * b1 = foo->GetData<Bar1>();
Bar2 * b2 = foo->GetData<Bar2>();
```

Do it as this, it won't compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `<T>` in the template member declaration :

```
 template <typename T>  T* GetData();
```

instead of :

```
 template <typename T>  T* GetData<T>();
```